# Pandas: how to convert a cell with multiple values to multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, converters

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Name asn  count
Org1 asn1,asn2 1
org2 asn3      2
org3 asn4,asn5 5
```

I would like to convert my DataFrame to look like this:

```
Name asn  count
Org1 asn1 1
Org1 asn2 1 
org2 asn3 2
org3 asn4 5
Org3 asn5 5
```

I know used the following code to do it with two columns, but I am not sure how can I do it for three.

```
df2 = df.asn.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)          
df2.index = df.Name                                   
df2 = df2.stack().reset_index('Name')
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What is the data type of the DataFrame?  A string, a list, a ndarray?  Can you give an example of the code necessary to create the ndarray in the example?  It isn't really clear what the structure is like just by looking at it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Carrying on from the same idea, you could set a MultiIndex for `df2` and then stack. For example:

```
>>> df2 = df.asn.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)
>>> df2.index = df.set_index(['Name', 'count']).index
>>> df2.stack().reset_index(['Name', 'count'])
   Name  count     0
0  Org1      1  asn1
1  Org1      1  asn2
0  org2      2  asn3
0  org3      5  asn4
1  org3      5  asn5
```

You can then rename the column and set an index of your choosing.

Comment: How to split two columns with multiple values? for example, I have two columns like "ASN" and "ASN2" like the one stated in the above question?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

ctn = '''Name asn count
Org1 asn1,asn2 1
org2 asn3      2
org3 asn4,asn5 5'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(ctn), sep='\s*', engine='python')
s = df['asn'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
s.name = 'asn'
del df['asn']
df = df.join(s)

print df
```

Result:

```
   Name  count   asn
0  Org1      1  asn1
0  Org1      1  asn2
1  org2      2  asn3
2  org3      5  asn4
2  org3      5  asn5
```