# Pandas - splitting a string in some cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a column and some of the cells have multiple values I want to split, so they get into a new row.

This a sample from my dataframe:

```
        index   ref_made_call
0   58  Sean Wright
1   115 Nick Buchert
2   191 James Williams
3   196 Jason Phillips
4   266 Scott Wall
5   272 Curtis Blair
6   390 Bennett Salvatore
7   490 Derrick Stafford
8   600 Kevin Cutler
9   683 Josh Tiven
10  816 Bennett Salvatore
11  1014    Joe Crawford
12  1255    Scott Foster,Sean Wright
```

I want to split `Scott Foster,Sean Wright` so the dataframe would look like:

```
        index   ref_made_call
0   58  Sean Wright
1   115 Nick Buchert
2   191 James Williams
3   196 Jason Phillips
4   266 Scott Wall
5   272 Curtis Blair
6   390 Bennett Salvatore
7   490 Derrick Stafford
8   600 Kevin Cutler
9   683 Josh Tiven
10  816 Bennett Salvatore
11  1014    Joe Crawford
12  1255    Scott Foster
13       Sean Wright
```

I already looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605352/pandas-how-to-convert-a-cell-with-multiple-values-to-multiple-rows) but it doesn't make what I want.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `str.split` + `stack`

```
df.set_index('index') \
    .ref_made_call.str.split(',', expand=True) \
    .stack().reset_index(-1, drop=True) \
    .reset_index(name='ref_made_call')

    index      ref_made_call
0      58        Sean Wright
1     115       Nick Buchert
2     191     James Williams
3     196     Jason Phillips
4     266         Scott Wall
5     272       Curtis Blair
6     390  Bennett Salvatore
7     490   Derrick Stafford
8     600       Kevin Cutler
9     683         Josh Tiven
10    816  Bennett Salvatore
11   1014       Joe Crawford
12   1255       Scott Foster
13   1255        Sean Wright
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!