# Group integers values into a single string cell with comma using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a DateFrame :

```
class    value
  1        2
  1        3
  1        5
  2        8
  3        1
  3        2
  4        20
  4        33
  .        .  
  .        .
```

I'm looknig for a way to add a string column (*str_values*) that will contain all values of a given class as a string with commas. The desire output is:

```
class    value    str_values
  1        2        2,3,5
  1        3        2,3,5
  1        5        2,3,5
  2        8          8
  3        1         1,2
  3        2         1,2
  4        20       20,33
  4        33       20,33
  .        .          .
  .        .          .
```

In other words, I'm looking to do the opposite as what described here: [Pandas: how to convert a cell with multiple values to multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605352/pandas-how-to-convert-a-cell-with-multiple-values-to-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 3):

Use, [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform)

```
df.astype(str).groupby(['class'])['value'].transform(",".join)
```

---

```
0    2,3,5
1    2,3,5
2    2,3,5
3        8
4      1,2
5      1,2
6    20,33
7    20,33
....
```

Comment: Thanks, your method answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df.merge(df['value'].astype(str).groupby(df['class']).agg(','.join).rename('str_values'),
         left_on='class', right_index=True)
```

output:

```
   class  value str_values
0      1      2      2,3,5
1      1      3      2,3,5
2      1      5      2,3,5
3      2      8          8
4      3      1        1,2
5      3      2        1,2
6      4     20      20,33
7      4     33      20,33
```